# How to render my Sudoku generator results to html table using Django?

Tags: javascript, python, html, django, sudoku

I am pretty new to Django and currently making a Sudoku web app. I wrote a python program to generate the Sudoku games, here is an example of the result/matrix looks like when i run the code (Sudoku Generator.py).

```
[[3, 8, 2, 7, 5, 6, 1, 4, 9],[1, 4, 5, 2, 3, 9, 6, 7, 8],[6, 7, 9, 1, 4, 8, 2, 3, 5],[2, 1, 3, 4, 6, 5, 8, 9, 7],[4, 5, 6, 8, 9, 7, 3, 1, 2],[7, 9, 8, 3, 1, 2, 4, 5, 6],[5, 2, 1, 6, 7, 3, 9, 8, 4],[8, 3, 7, 9, 2, 4, 5, 6, 1],[9, 6, 4, 5, 8, 1, 7, 2, 3]]
```

My question is, how can I render all these generated numbers to my html file? here is the html codes i've created under the templates:

```html
{% extends 'base.html' %}
{% block sudoku %}

<style>
table { border-collapse: collapse; font-family: Calibri, sans-serif; }
colgroup, tbody { border: solid medium; }
td { border: solid thin; height: 1.4em; width: 1.4em; text-align: center; padding: 0; }
</style>
        <table>
          <caption>Sudoku of the day</caption>
          <colgroup><col><col><col>
          <colgroup><col><col><col>
          <colgroup><col><col><col>
          <tbody>
           <tr> <td> <td>  <td> <td> <td>  <td> <td> <td>  <td>
           <tr> <td>  <td> <td>  <td>  <td> <td>  <td>  <td> <td>
           <tr> <td> <td>  <td>  <td>  <td>  <td>  <td>  <td>  <td>
          <tbody>
           <tr> <td> <td>  <td> <td>  <td> <td>  <td> <td>  <td>
           <tr> <td>  <td>  <td>  <td>  <td>  <td>  <td>  <td>  <td>
           <tr> <td> <td>  <td>  <td> <td>  <td> <td>  <td>  <td>
          <tbody>
           <tr> <td> <td>  <td>  <td>  <td> <td>  <td>  <td>  <td>
           <tr> <td>  <td>  <td>  <td>  <td> <td>  <td>  <td>  <td>
           <tr> <td> <td>  <td>  <td> <td>  <td> <td>  <td>  <td>
        </table>
{% endblock %}
```

Basically what I wanted is to get each number populated to each tag accordingly; also, whenever clicks "next game" button, the board will refresh and generate another bunch of numbers to form a new game.

Attached is the screen shot of my Django work project directory so far: 
[mysite directory](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YAbCg.png)

Now I totally got stuck, not sure if what i've done so far is correct and don't know what to do next... Anyone can help??

Comment: Hint: you can access the element of the 3rd row and 5th column with `{{ mylist.3.5 }}` in the template.

Comment: Use templating in order to iterate through the matrix and generate the table programatically. See the `for` loop in https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/topics/templates/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Asuming you use the variable `sudoku_numbers` to store your array of numbers, then in the template you can use something like this:

```
<table>
  {% for row in sudoku_numbers %}
    <tr>
      {% for col in row %}
        <td>{{ col }}</td>
      {% endfor %}
    </tr>
  {% endfor %}
</table>
```

Comment: sorry for the late reply. It worked very well! thank you so much. I am currently trying to figure out how to POST each number (together with user's input) to Views for comparison, and every number should be passing through in the right position/index. I knew it is easy to post the input data via form in Django, but how about the non-input data? do i need to write something like "<input autocomplete="off" maxlength="1" name="{{ [row][col] }}">" in <td> to index each number? and neither i know the correct format of naming in Jinjia for nested loop. Wondering if you got any idea?

Comment: The last paragraph in http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs/2.10/tricks/#accessing-the-parent-loop would suggest that you can use `[ {{ rowloop.index }} ][ {{ loop.index }} ]` when you set `{% set rowloop = loop %}` in the outer loop.

Comment: Hi many thanks for the inspiration and quick response. It is working, and for your quick information- "set" tag is actually not supported in Django, but "with" does. Also, no spaces besides the "=".